# passing variable in ajax from one page to another

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a form where

```
<form method="post" id="insert_form">
    <div class="table-repsonsive">
        <span id="error"></span>
        <table  class="css-serial" class="table table-bordered" id="item_table">
            <thead>
                <h5>Package Name:-<input type="text" name="packname" /><input type="hidden" id="packname" name="packname" value="<?php $packname;?>" /></h5>
                <tr>
                    <th>sl.no</th>
                    <th>Service Type</th>
                    <th>Service Name</th>
                    <th>Sessions</th>
                    <th><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-xs add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Add Services</button></th>
                </tr>

            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
        <div align="center">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Save" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

with the script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var count = 0;

    $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
        count++;
        var html = '';
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
        html += '<input type="hidden" name="item_name[]" class="form-control item_name" />';
        html += '<td><select name="item_category[]" class="form-control item_category" data-sub_category_id="'+count+'"><option value="">Select Service Type</option><?php echo fill_select_box($connect, "0"); ?></select></td>';
        html += '<td><select name="item_sub_category[]" class="form-control item_sub_category" id="item_sub_category'+count+'"><option value="">Select Service Name</option></select></td>';
        html +='<td><input type="text" name="nosessions[]" class="form-control nosessions" /></td>';
        html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td>';
        $('tbody').append(html);
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });

    $(document).on('change', '.item_category', function(){
        var category_id = $(this).val();
        var sub_category_id = $(this).data('sub_category_id');
        $.ajax({
            url:"fill_sub_category.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{category_id:category_id},
            success:function(data)
            {
                var html = '<option value="">Select Sub Category</option>';
                html += data;
                $('#item_sub_category'+sub_category_id).html(html);
            }
        })
    });

    $('#insert_form').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var error = '';


        $('.item_category').each(function() {
            var count = 1;

            if($(this).val() == '')
            {
                error += '<p>Select Item Category at '+count+' row</p>';
                return false;
            }

            count = count + 1;

        });

        $('.item_sub_category').each(function(){

            var count = 1;

            if($(this).val() == '') {
                error += '<p>Select Item Sub category '+count+' Row</p> ';
                return false;
            }

            count = count + 1;

        });
        $('.nosessions').each(function(){

            var count = 1;

            if($(this).val() == '') {
                error += '<p>Select no of sessions '+count+' Row</p> ';
                return false;
            }

            count = count + 1;

        });

        var form_data = $(this).serialize();

        if(error == '') {
            $.ajax({
                url:"insert.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:form_data,
                success:function(data) {
                    if(data == 'ok') {
                        $('#item_table').find('tr:gt(0)').remove();
                        $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Item Details Saved</div>');
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+error+'</div>');
        }
    });
});
```

I need to get packname to the inser table insert.php please anybody help i dont understand ajax much . how to send the packname it is the overall name given to all other services so i need to pass packname in that array for every entry.Packname is single one for all these entries done and it should enter in each row inserted .

Comment: change var form_data = $(this).serialize() to var form_data = new FormData(); and try.

Comment: Please describe your problem what are you need ?

Answer (score 0):

> The [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) class provides a way to easily construct a set of key/value pairs representing form fields and their values.

After using it your script would look like:

```html
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

      var count = 0;

      $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
        count++;
        var html = '';
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
        html += '<input type="hidden" name="item_name[]" class="form-control item_name" />';
        html += '<td><select name="item_category[]" class="form-control item_category" data-sub_category_id="'+count+'"><option value="">Select Service Type</option><?php echo fill_select_box($connect, "0"); ?></select></td>';
        html += '<td><select name="item_sub_category[]" class="form-control item_sub_category" id="item_sub_category'+count+'"><option value="">Select Service Name</option></select></td>';
        html +='<td><input type="text" name="nosessions[]" class="form-control nosessions" /></td>';
        html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td>';
        $('tbody').append(html);
      });

      $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      });

      $(document).on('change', '.item_category', function(){
        var category_id = $(this).val();
        var sub_category_id = $(this).data('sub_category_id');
        $.ajax({
          url:"fill_sub_category.php",
          method:"POST",
          data:{category_id:category_id},
          success:function(data)
          {
            var html = '<option value="">Select Sub Category</option>';
            html += data;
            $('#item_sub_category'+sub_category_id).html(html);
          }
        })
      });

      $('#insert_form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var error = '';


        $('.item_category').each(function(){
          var count = 1;

          if($(this).val() == '')
          {
            error += '<p>Select Item Category at '+count+' row</p>';
            return false;
          }

          count = count + 1;

        });

        $('.item_sub_category').each(function(){

          var count = 1;

          if($(this).val() == '')
          {
            error += '<p>Select Item Sub category '+count+' Row</p> ';
            return false;
          }

          count = count + 1;

        });
        $('.nosessions').each(function(){

          var count = 1;

          if($(this).val() == '')
          {
            error += '<p>Select no of sessions '+count+' Row</p> ';
            return false;
          }

          count = count + 1;

        });

        var form_data = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        if(error == '')
        {
          $.ajax({
            url:"insert.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:form_data,
            success:function(data)
            {
              if(data == 'ok')
              {
                $('#item_table').find('tr:gt(0)').remove();
                $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Item Details Saved</div>');
              }
            }
          });
        }
        else
        {
          $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+error+'</div>');
        }

      });

    });
</script>
```

In addition, you may need to change:

```html
<h5>Package Name:-<input type="text" name="packname" /><input type="hidden" id="packname" name="packname" value="<?php $packname;?>" /></h5>
```

Into:

```html
<h5>Package Name:-<input type="text" name="packname" value="<?php $packname;?>" disabled="disabled" /></h5>
<input type="hidden" id="packname" name="packname" value="<?php $packname;?>" />
```